# What event should I bind in a select element to detect a selection change?

Tags: angular, event-handling

I would like to update the interpolated text on a form page and also recalculate values when the user selects a new value in a

```
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="unitlabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Units</label>
    <select name="Units"
    [(ngModel)] = "units"
    (onTouched)="updateUnits()">
      <option value="US" selected>US</option>
      <option value="Metric">Metric</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIsten to the `change` event

```
<select name="Units"
[(ngModel)] = "units"
(change)="updateUnits()">
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where is this type of event is documented?

Comment: @NetworkEffects https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change